# Using const_cast correctly with third party library

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I have a large library that implements some immutable data structures. As you can imagine, nearly everything in it is `const` qualified. There are a few select pieces that are not const, such as reference counters. In order to deal with the reference counters embedded in structures that are accessed exclusively through `const` methods and pointers, the `mutable` keyword is used. Example below in `Node`. This works well, and my reading of the docs says this is fine.

The problem I'm facing is that I'd also like to track some parts of the data structure using Boost.Intrusive containers, but those containers do not have const methods.

```
boost::intrusive::list my_bi_list; // as an example

struct Node {
  mutable boost::intrusive::list_member_hook<> bi_hook;
  mutable std::atomic<int> refcount;

  // const T a;
  // const T b;
  // ...

  inline void put() const {
    ...
    my_bi_list.push_back(*this); // PROBLEM here
  }
};
```

In `Node` above, `*this` is used to put the current `Node` instance on the intrusive list, but that interface takes a non-`const` reference, resulting in your standard C++ qualifier discarded errors.

I've been reading about `const_cast` (e.g. `push_back(const_cast<Node&>(*this)`), but it isn't at all clear even after reading the docs I've found that I'm venturing into undefined behavior territory.

Any guidance here would be appreciated (especially any technique to avoid this entirely!)

Thanks

Comment: what is `my_bi_list`?

Comment: That is a reference to a boost::intrusive::list

Comment: Looks like a hole in the standard for not allowing `const` inheritance...

Answer (score 0):

Use [`boost::cref(x)`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/ref.html):

> boost::cref(x) returns a boost::reference_wrapper(x)

This way, you're using boost's reference library and does implicit conversions.

Answer (score 0):

You are venturing into undefined behavior territory. From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast) (under Notes):

> const_cast makes it possible to form a reference or pointer to non-const type that is actually referring to a const object or a reference or pointer to non-volatile type that is actually referring to a volatile object. Modifying a const object through a non-const access path and referring to a volatile object through a non-volatile glvalue results in undefined behavior.

Using const objects in combination with intrusive containers in general is not possible directly. What you could do is wrap the types you want to put into the intrusive containers in your own non-const type.